# Pretty Printer perl module not working as expected

Tags: html, perl, indentation

I'm trying to follow the example in the synopsis of [`HTML::PrettyPrinter`](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML%3a%3aPrettyPrinter). I corrected the typo to create a `FileHandle`:

```
my $fh = new FileHandle ">E:\\test.html";
```

Now the file gets created but I'm getting another error:

> Can't call method "isa" on an undefined value at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/HTML/PrettyPrinter.pm line 414.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
use HTML::TreeBuilder;
# generate a HTML syntax tree
my $tree = new HTML::TreeBuilder;
$tree->parse_file("E:\\file.html");
# modify the tree if you want

use HTML::PrettyPrinter;
my $hpp = new HTML::PrettyPrinter ('linelength' => 130,'quote_attr' => 1);
# configure
$hpp->set_force_nl(1,qw(body head));             # for tags
$hpp->set_force_nl(1,qw(@SECTIONS));             # as above
$hpp->set_nl_inside(0,'default!');               # for all tags

# format the source
my $linearray_ref = $hpp->format($tree);
print @$linearray_ref;

# alternative: print directly to filehandle
use FileHandle;
my $fh = new FileHandle ">E:\\test.html";
if (defined $fh) {
  $hpp->select($fh);
  $hpp->format();
  undef $fh;
  $hpp->select(undef),  
}
```

Comment: Do you have `use strict; use warnings;` at the top of your script?

Comment: Well, you should! It won't solve your problem automatically but may give some clues as to what is happening.

Comment: Does it die when `$hpp->format($tree||die 'no $tree');`?

Comment: its prints in single line now @mpapec

Comment: I mean all the errors are gone once I pass the line you provided in the filehandling area. but indension doesn't work instead it prints the whole thing in single line

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line is causing the error:

```
$hpp->format();
```

`HTML::PrettyPrinter::format` attempts to call `isa` on the first argument:

```
411 sub format {
412  my ($self, $element, $indent, $lar) = @_;
413  # $lar = line array ref
414  confess "Need an HTML::Element" unless $element->isa('HTML::Element');
     ...
```

Which causes the error you're getting if it is `undef`. Passing `$tree` (which `isa HTML::Element`) as the first argument populates the file correctly:

```
$hpp->format($tree);
```